# HashSet<T> GetHashcode optimization

Tags: c#, performance, graph, hashcode

I have the following structure in C# to represent a graph edge:

```
struct Edge
{
    public Edge(int leftA, int leftB, int leftC, int leftD, int rightA, int rightB, int rightC, int rightD)
    {
        LeftIdA = leftA;
        LeftIdB = leftB;
        LeftIdC = leftC;
        LeftIdD = leftD;

        RightIdA = rightA;
        RightIdB = rightB;
        RightIdC = rightC;
        RightIdD = rightD;
    }

    public readonly int LeftIdA;
    public readonly int LeftIdB;
    public readonly int LeftIdC;
    public readonly int LeftIdD;

    public readonly int RightIdA;
    public readonly int RightIdB;
    public readonly int RightIdC;
    public readonly int RightIdD;
}
```

And need to store a lot of it (about 5 millions) in a HashSet so there is no duplicates. What would be a good implementation for GetHashCode so it is optimized for speed?

I have tried to store the 4 bits of each id in the returned integer like this:

```
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int A = LeftIdA & 0xF;
        int B = LeftIdB & 0xF;
        int C = LeftIdC & 0xF;
        int D = LeftIdD & 0xF;

        int E = RightIdA & 0xF;
        int F = RightIdB & 0xF;
        int G = RightIdC & 0xF;
        int H = RightIdD & 0xF;

        int result = A;
        result = (result << 4) | B;
        result = (result << 4) | C;
        result = (result << 4) | D;
        result = (result << 4) | E;
        result = (result << 4) | F;
        result = (result << 4) | G;
        result = (result << 4) | H;

        return result;
    }
```

but it is like 80% slower than adding the items to a list.

Comment: If you figured out *unique hash* for your data set  (which you seem to have), than simply pre-grow `Dictionary` to large number of items (i.e. twice as you expect?) and see if it is fast enough (`HashSet` does not seem to have "pre-grow" method).

Comment: This hashing strategy does not seem to guarantee uniqueness, so it is unsuitable as the key of a dictionary.  Otherwise, I would agree.

Comment: @CSJ: The hash code doesn't need to be unique. For any data type containing more than 32 bits of data, it's impossible to create a unique 32 bit hash code.

Comment: @Guffa: Indeed. However, it can't be used to select dictionary keys unless its values are unique.  That's why a hashset is the appropriate data structure to use, not a dictionary.

Comment: @CSJ: It's not the hash code that determines the uniqueness, but the equality comparison. That's the same for the HashSet and the Dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be a good implementation for GetHashCode so it is optimized for speed?

Since all your fields are read-only, your best bet is probably to pre-compute the hashcode in the constructor, and then just return that from `GetHashCode`.

To precalculate the hashcode, you can use the formula from Guffa's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding into the `HashSet` will take longer, and it's not because of any bad strategy in the 
`GetHashCode()` implementation.  In fact, this implementation looks quite good.  A `HashSet` has to do all kinds of crazy crap inside like set up buckets and slot the things into them.

The performance gain is in the finding of elements in the hashset.  Try adding 5 million distinct items to a list, and to a hashset, and see which container is able to tell you more quickly if it contains a particular Edge or not.  You might be willing to pay the less-than-double setup time then.

Comment: Good point. for sure it will be slow, but can it be taken closer to a list? Anyway adding to a list will not garantee the uniqueness of the items.

Answer (score 0):

To work best, the hash code should give as few collisions as possible, i.e. produce as varied hash codes as possible.

Try to produce the hash code so that that all the data from all the members are used:

```
public override int GetHashCode() {
  return
    LeftIdA ^ LeftIdB ^ LeftIdC ^ LeftIdD ^
    RightIdA ^ RightIdB ^ RightIdC ^ RightIdD;
}
```

Multiplying with a prime number gives very good distribution, so you should test if that gives better performance in your case:

```
public override int GetHashCode() {
  return
    ((((((LeftIdA * 251 + LeftIdB) * 251 + LeftIdC) * 251 +
    LeftIdD) * 251 + RightIdA) * 251 + RightIdB) * 251 +
    RightIdC) * 251 + RightIdD;
}
```

Note: Make sure that you also provide an optimised equality comparison for the struct. The default implementation would use reflection to determine all members to be compared, and thus be pretty slow.

#### Edit:

I made some testing, and with the second implementation I can add 5 million items to the HashSet in about two seconds.

Comment: Your implementation adds the problem of overflowing the integer.